# How to overlay page partially when fancybox.showloading shows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox-2

I have following code:

html:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       1111111111111
    </li>
    <li>
       22222222222222
    </li>
    <li>
       33333333333333
    </li>
    <li>
       44444444444444
    </li>
    <li>
       555555555555555
    </li>
    <li>
       66666666666666
    </li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>    
<div type="button" class="on">on </div>
<div type="button" class="off">off </div>
```

js:

```
$(".on").click(function(){
    $.fancybox.showLoading();  
});
$(".off").click(function(){
    $.fancybox.hideLoading();  
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PudLq/580/)

you can click on `on` or `off` it leads to showing/hiding animation.

I want that concrete html tag(`ul` in my exampel) was overlayed when animation shows.

following area:

[image]

Please help to correct my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it should require a few CSS changes, and little bit of math in your click event.  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/PudLq/586/)

Start by giving your target element some sort of identifier:

```
<ul id="target">
    <li>
       1111111111111
    </li>
    <li>
       22222222222222
    </li>
    <li>
       33333333333333
    </li>
    <li>
       44444444444444
    </li>
    <li>
       555555555555555
    </li>
    <li>
       66666666666666
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Then since by default a `<ul>` is a block object, we should make it inline-block to make it easier to get its width:

```
#target {
    display:inline-block;
    border: solid 1px;
}
#overlay {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Finally, in the click event we will obtain the target's width, subtract the width of the popup loader, and divide the remaining width by 2 to center it up. The same with the height:

```
$(".on").click(function(){
    var target = $('#target');
    var overlay = $('#overlay');
    overlay.width(target.width()).height(target.height()).css({
        'left': target.position().left,
        'top': target.position().top
    }).fadeIn(200);
    $.fancybox.showLoading();
    $('#fancybox-loading').css({
        'left': (target.width() - $('#fancybox-loading').width()) / 2,
        'top': (target.height() - $('#fancybox-loading').height()) / 2,
        'margin': 0
    });
});
$(".off").click(function(){
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(200);
    $.fancybox.hideLoading();  
});
```

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: In your demo area doesn't dim

Comment: Ahhh I see one second. I will fix.

Comment: @gstackoverflow Updated the answer, and the fiddle. Something like this?

Comment: you are forgot about UnNdim)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var $el = $('ul');
var $cover = $('#dummy');
var coverPos = $el.position();

$cover.css({
    position:'absolute',
    top: coverPos.top,
    left:coverPos.left,
    width:$el.width()+'px',
    height:$el.height()+'px',
    background:'#f00'
}).show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/PudLq/582/

A `ul` has `display:block;`. If you only want the block to cover the width of the text, you'll need to calculate the required width of the `ul`. Here's the same code where the `ul` has an arbitrary width of `150px`.

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/PudLq/583/

**Edit**

To also position the 'loading' icon in the center of the element....

```
$('#fancybox-loading').css({
    position:'absolute',
    top: coverPos.top + ($el.height()/2),
    left:coverPos.left + ($el.width()/2),
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/PudLq/585/

Comment: I also want that animation show in the center oberlayed area

Comment: @gstack I've not used FancyBox, so I'm not sure this is really the right approach. But I've updated my answer anyway.

Comment: good answer but unfortunately I have already accept one right answer and cannot accept one more. But I up it